# Can PhD be written as PH.D in a name card?

Tags: abbreviations

I came across a name card from an academic staff, with title after the name written as PH.D

Is this proper?

WW

Comment: Ideally, it should be "Ph. D."... so I would say both your versions are technically wrong.

Comment: @keshlam Ideally to whom?

Comment: If a name card is the same as a business card, it may have been a purely stylistic choice.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, there are [many ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy) to abbreviate it:

> Doctor of Philosophy, abbreviated as **PhD, Ph.D., D.Phil., or DPhil** in English-speaking countries and originally as Dr.Philos. or Dr.Phil. (for the Latin philosophiae doctor or doctor philosophiae), is in many countries a postgraduate academic degree awarded by universities.

It doesn't seem that your exact example is listed here, as it's missing the second period and the "h" is capitalized but if all the text on the card is in uppercase, that could explain the capitalized "h".

As for me, the Ph.D. option makes sense. Seeing as it is two separate words that have been turned into a single abbreviation.

Comment: Incidentally, I wouldn't recommend using "Dr. Phil." in America, because. . . https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phil_McGraw

Comment: *D.Phil* in England is specifically a doctorate from the University of Oxford.  The difference is important in a few academic contexts, though allowances are made for Americans and other barbarian scholars.